# Compute Django Model Field Value on First Access (Lazy Field)

Tags: python, django, django-models

**Description:**

I want to add a new field to an existing Django model.
The value of this field for each instance can be computed using an external API.

Since there are already a large number of instances saved in the database and the external API has a quota, it is not a good idea to compute this field for every instance on database migration.

It worths mentioning that this field will be rarely accessed.

**Question:**

Is it possible to compute the value, only on the first access to that specific field and save it in the database for future uses?
Is there an standard way of handling this situation?

Comment: You can use a property or method via which you acccess the field. There you can use the existing value or make the API-call.

Comment: @schwobaseggl technically correct, BUT: would you _really_ consider something like an accessor doing an API call and a db update as something fundamentally sane and well designed ?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers If it handles errors well, why not. Sometimes a synchronous API-call is needed. I wouldn't consider it fundamentaly wrong to put it lazily where the retrieved value is actually accessed. After all, common django fields are nothing but lazy hooks into an external service (the database).

Comment: @schwobaseggl "common django fields" are NOT "lazy hooks into an external service", they are plain attributes (unless they've been explicitely deferred but then you did ask for it - and even then it's only a read - not an update - to a service that will prevent your whole site to work if down anyway).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers True, but they are still populated synchronously during the request. Similarly, your website might depend on a certain API to be available. For the case at hand, there might, of course, be better options.

Comment: "but they are still populated synchronously during the request." => they are populated when you get your model instance from the database indeed (not necessarily "during the request" - hopefully Django models are independant from the http request cycle), but really that's the very first thing you expect from an ORM : load your data from the database. As such it doesn't break any expectation, quite on the contrary. FWIW, you can even instanciate models without saving them and access their attributes (as long as no foreignkey is involved of course).

Answer (score 1):

The general answer is "wrap the field in a `property` (or other descriptor), ie:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    _lazy = models.WhateverField(
      db_column="lazy",
      blank=True, 
      null=True,  
      default=None
      )

    @property
    def lazy(self):
        if self._lazy is None:
            self._lazy = get_the_value_from_api_call(...) 
            self.save(update_fields=["_lazy"])
        return self._lazy

    # if you want to be able to set the property - else
    # ignore this part and `MyModel.lazy` will become
    # read-only 
    @lazy.setter
    def lazy(self, value):
        self._lazy = value
```

BUT I would definitly NOT allow this in my team - I do not expect a getter to do an HTTP request and update the database - and I strongly suggest you find a better (robust, reliable and predictable) way to solve the *real* problem which is, mainly, handling the API quota.

Comment: I would appreciate any suggestions about "the better way".

Comment: @KayvanMazaheri I'm afraid it's impossible to suggest anything sensible without knowing _much_ more about your project's specs, constraints etc, and I'm not sure I actually want to learn that much about your project - I have mine to take care of and it already requires most of my poor brain cells ;-)